# Unknown Type Name 'Type' Error in Yacc and Lex Compilation

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm currently working on a compiler project using Yacc and Lex, and I'm running into an error that I can't seem to resolve. When I compile my code using the GCC, I get an error message: yacc.y:20:8: error: unknown type name 'Type'.

Here is the related part of my yacc.y file:

```
%{
#include "symbol_table.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex(void);
void check_types(float val1, float val2);
Type get_type_from_value(float value);
void check_type(float value, const char *lexeme);

%}

%union {
       char* lexeme;            //name of an identifier
       float value;            //attribute of a token of type NUM
       Type type;              //attribute of a token of type Type
       }
```

And here is the related part of my symbol_table.h file:

```
#ifndef SYMBOL_TABLE_H
#define SYMBOL_TABLE_H

typedef enum {
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
  TYPE_UNDEFINED
} Type;

void symbol_table_init();
void symbol_table_insert(const char *lexeme, float value, Type type);
Type symbol_table_get_type(const char *lexeme);
float symbol_table_lookup(const char *lexeme);

#endif
```

The error points to the line where I'm trying to use Type in my yacc.y file. I've already included symbol_table.h in yacc.y where Type is defined. I'm also using the -d flag with Yacc to generate the header file.

I've tried:

- Ensuring the header guards are correct in symbol_table.h.
- Cleaning my project directory and recompiling everything.
- Making sure all my source files are in the same directory.
- Using absolute paths in my #include directives.
- Checking the versions of Yacc, Lex, and GCC (they all seem to be fine).

However, I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!